# How to prevent Ubuntu/XUbuntu from automounting repositories from Ubuntu CDs?

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, repository, software-sources, cd

Whenever I insert an  Ubuntu/XUbuntu CD into my XUbuntu PC the system recognizes it as a package repository. I dislike this behaviour as it is generally useless (except for those people having no broadband Internet connection) and prevents me from erasing and reusing the CD-RW. Can I disable this functionality?

Comment: Does this still happen with the CD entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` commented out (by putting `#` in front of these lines)? You can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` to open an `xfce4-terminal` window, run `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old` to back it up, and then `gksu mousepad /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit it as `root`. (These instructions are Xubuntu-specific.) I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I don't actually *think* this is always sufficient to prevent the behavior you're describing...but it's important to check first, in case this is sufficient.

Comment: In 12.04, mousepad is replaced by leafpad. so, the command will be `gksu leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 3):

I think *(97% sure)* you are referring to this message box.

[image: Distribution upgrade message box]

To disable it, open a terminal and run the command below. (Then log out and log in again, to see that this annoying message box no longer appears.)

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier auto-launch false
```

Ubuntu (though not Xubuntu) also provides a neat graphical graphical way to do this:

Go to `System Settings` --> `Details` --> `Removable Media` --> `Software` and select *Do nothing*.